# GNU make: How to process a file list created with $(file)?

Tags: bash, gnu-make

There is a file list in a make variable. The file list is too long for one command line. The list can be written into a file with the $(file) make function.
$(file) always appends a newline, so eventually the list file will contain a space separated list of filenames and a newline at the end.
Question: how can this be processed with bash commands in a recipe?
I tried some common solutions:

```
while read -r -d ' ' l; do echo $l; done <listfile
```

This won't process the last file, as there is no space after it. A space can be appended before creating the file, but then the newline will be interpreted as a filename and the command fails.

```
xargs -n 1 -d " " -i echo {} <listfile
```

Same issue: the newline at the end is interpreted as a filename.

Since this is quite a common task in makefiles, there should be a simple and efficient solution. The solution should work under Cygwin/MSYS2/EZWinPorts, CR/LF should not matter. Any ideas better than removing the newline with tr?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is creating a newline separated list with make. I did that with deleting the list file and then

```
$(foreach f,$(file_list),$(file >>listfile,$f))
```

The internal $(file) function should be faster than calling external tools - as long as it does not need to be called 300 times. Implementing the $(foreach) inside a single $(file) might be more efficient, but then the CR/LF would need to be specified explicitly, and who knows whether it's good for xargs. This way it should be consistent across the toolchain.
The file list can be processed this way:

```
xargs -a filelist -i do_something {}
```

Tested with Cygwin and MSYS2.

Comment: Another solution would be to create recipe lines on the fly with a `make` iteration (`subst`, `foreach` etc.). While you are right that list processing is common in build systems, the very basic nature of a list and the complex tasks on it prevent a common solution, not just in `make`. You may want to take a look at https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt for a `GNU make` library which features a lot of helper functions.

Comment: I managed to solve the task inside make. The problem is that after producing the files, make has to be restarted (it does automatically) to fetch the new recipes. It works, but it's slow. I'd like to reduce the number of restarts during a typical build. It's now 8, and could be reduced to 4 by doing the list processing in the shell. Checking the toolkit you referred. I'll definitely learn from it, but it's a bit of an overkill, similar to https://gmsl.sourceforge.io/. I hoped there was a simple solution... Thanks for looking into this anyway!

Comment: What operation do you want to execute on the filename list? I think the `echo` up there serves only as a placeholder, no?

Comment: Call a code generator that generates code for several AUTOSAR BSW modules, and then create lists of generated files for each module. The current operation is that a "raw" file list is created first in a make include file, make is restarted to fetch the variable defined in that file, processes the raw list to create separate lists for each BSW module, then restarts again to fetch the module-specific file lists. If the list could be processed by the shell, the module-specific lists could be created from the same recipe and probably from the same shell, halving the number of restarts...

Comment: And of course the lists are eventually used in dynamically generated recipes. It's a bit complicated but works very well. Just want to optimize it a bit because the lot of make restarts are suboptimal and waste some time.

Comment: Can you roughly depict the chain of commands? Did you consider writing them as pattern rules?

Comment: 1: run the generator and parse the log with sed to produce the raw file list (echo/sed), then make restarts. 2: make includes the raw list, and dynamic rules for each module produce the module-specific lists ($(file), then make restarts again. 3: the module-specific lists are included and used in various other rules

Comment: Now the improvement would be generating the raw list and filtering it for the modules in one run, without having to restart make. To this, the list of modules needs to be generated by make, and some loop in the shell can then iterate through it. Of course it only makes sense if easy to implement and easy to understand, otherwise I'd just keep the current slow but elegant solution :)

Comment: As the restart of `make` with a small makefile is barely noticeable, I suspect that your slow restarts come from an enormous variable list which gets reconstructed each time (maybe intensified by accesses to the shell or worse, network resources). Could that be? Or is the generator called every time? I am a bit puzzled where you lose the build time - make itself is really fast, in the range of the compilation time of a single non-trivial C++ file.

Comment: Correct. Make must look into ~90 modules and fetch the generated files for them at each restart, and also add the static sources with $(wildcard). Make itself might be fast, but file operations are slow. Probably I should do something about this... Create a file list at the first restart (or even keep it in a file) and just use that later. Getting complicated...